# Reflection/Lookup on Django model doesn't find internationalized (shadow) fields

Tags: django, django-modeltranslation

I use a CMS that does a mapping of my models through an API at runtime.

It works fine, except for localized fields, because I use https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/registration.html which add "shadow" fields that are obviously not mapped (they're not present in the model itself, but added through "register")

Is there any way I can tell my model that it owns those fields? 
It can find the `label` field, but misses the `label_fr` and `label_en` which are dynamically added at runtime.

Here is the `translation.py`:

```
from modeltranslation.translator import translator, TranslationOptions

from tfp_backoffice.apps.org.models import Org


class OrgTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
  """
  See https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/registration.html
  """
  fields = ('label',)
  required_languages = ('fr',)  # ex: {'de': ('title', 'text'), 'default': ('title',)}


translator.register(Org, OrgTranslationOptions)
```

I use https://github.com/jet-admin/jet-django and I noticed that the response of the `/model_descriptions` endpoint only returns the `label` field.

I suspect this being the code being called when calling the endpoint https://github.com/jet-admin/jet-django/blob/94b0bb1451e768c7c3b6dadf9830d982914fe6c9/jet_django/views/model_description.py#L12

Basically, I've installed `django-modeltranslation` and `jet-django` apps, the later serves an API that is consumed by [JET Admin UI](https://jetadmin.io/) and is used to do the models lookup.

I don't know if my issue must be fixed in jet-django itself, or if django provides a feature for shadow fields like that.

Comment: You don't need to show _translation.py_, it's just standard way of specifying the fields to translate. What we need to know, is what's the exact problem: what CMS are you using, how does the mapping happen, what's the code that doesn't return what you'd want.

Comment: I didn't know that's standard way of doing translations. I thought the way of doing it through `register` was specific to the app.

Comment: sorry I meant that's how modeltranslation works. But this code isn't your issue, and it's totally unclear what you mean by "the model can find the `label` field but misses the `label_fr` field". What code "finds" a field? What code does a "mapping"?

Comment: Thanks, I've added additional information

Comment: I found [this](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/registration.html#precautions-regarding-registration-approach). When you retrieve an instance of a translated object, (e.g. a 'Post' with a field `text` that is translated), you'll see that `post._meta.fields` contains the translated fields, so `text`, `text_fr`, `text_de`. But the issue is probably that the jet API code is executed before the modeltranslation registration. Not sure how to solve that, you may want to ask the guys from jet-admin.

Comment: The fields are retrieved [here](https://github.com/jet-admin/jet-django/blob/94b0bb1451e768c7c3b6dadf9830d982914fe6c9/jet_django/admin/model_description.py#L44) using `Model._meta.get_fields()`. So it should work if the translation registration runs before the JetAdmin registration. Could it be that changing the order of the apps in your settings.py would do the job?

Comment: Damn, totally could, hadn't thought about that! I'll give it a try, thanks :)

Comment: @dirkgroten Indeed it worked. If you want to write an actual answer I'll accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django-modeltranslation uses a registration approach, described [here](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/registration.html#precautions-regarding-registration-approach), which means all models are patched when you launch your django app the first time. After django-modeltranslation is initialised, `Post._meta.fields` contains the translated fields `text_fr` and `text_de` in addition to `text`.

Looking at jet-django, it seems a `JetAdminModelDescription` is also initialised when the app is launched, the actual model fields are retrieved [here](https://github.com/jet-admin/jet-django/blob/94b0bb1451e768c7c3b6dadf9830d982914fe6c9/jet_django/admin/model_description.py#L44) using `Model._meta.get_fields()`.

So as long as jet-django is initialised after django-modeltranslations, the fields should be also available to JetAdmin.

Make sure you place jet-django *after* django-modeltranslation in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting and it should work.